# Opencart registration error

Tags: php, registration, opencart, notice

Had a really interesting error that I do not know how to resolve. After I registered as a new user and clicking the submit button, I get the chunk of error below:

**Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in public_html/mystore/system/library/mail.php on line 153Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in public_html/mystore/system/library/mail.php on line 153Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at public_html/mystore/index.php:104) in public_html/mystore/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 28Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at public_html/mystore/index.php:104) in public_html/mystore/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 29**

The interesting thing is, after this error comes out and I refresh the page, I am back to my site and AS A REGISTERED USER???? (ie. already logged in).

Is this something to do with my vqmod? Anyone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the error you have a problem with a variable passed to the mail class, I would look at line 153 of the mail class, from this you can trace your variable.

The error on your Cambodia page is a bit of a red herring as it is a header sent issue which is just due to the output from the error in your mail class.

The error should still allow a user to register but will fail to send the email of registration.